# SQL Server JOIN and SELECT CASE in 1 query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to combine these two queries so that 'Yes' is produced when HET = 1 and UOW = 3 in the TPS table and 'No' is produced otherwise. Is there a way to do this?

```
select 
   TPS.HET,
   TPS.UOW AS UOW
from controls
inner join TPS on
   ctrls.Priority_Score=TPS.score 
inner join TPS AS UOW on
   ctrls.Priority_Score=TPS.score

select 
   case when HET = '1' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as HET,
   case when UOW = '3' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as UOW from TPS
```

Comment: Why don't you simply add that case construct to the select clause of the first query?

Comment: Stick those two case statements underneath `SELECT` in your first query and you will have what you want (just make sure to add an extra comma to separate your fields)

Comment: Why are you doing this, `inner join TPS AS UOW on
   ctrls.Priority_Score=TPS.score`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
   case when TPS.HET = '1' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as HET,
   case when TPS.UOW = '3' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as UOW 
from controls
inner join TPS on
   ctrls.Priority_Score=TPS.score 
inner join TPS AS UOW on
   ctrls.Priority_Score=TPS.score
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add your `CASE WHEN statement` in your select.
Also, you need to combine your two `WHEN statement` into only one with a `AND` in order to get "Yes" only when HET is 1 and UOW is 3.

```
select  ExpectedResult = CASE WHEN TPS.HET = '1' AND TPS.UOW = '3' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END,
        TPS.HET,
        TPS.UOW AS UOW
from controls
inner join TPS on ctrls.Priority_Score=TPS.score 
inner join TPS AS UOW on ctrls.Priority_Score=TPS.score
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `and` in your `case` expression

```
case when HET = '1' and UOW = '3' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as
```

---

```
select 
   case when HET = '1' and UOW = '3' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as HET,
   case when HET = '1' and UOW = '3' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as UOW 
from controls
inner join TPS on
   ctrls.Priority_Score=TPS.score 
inner join TPS AS UOW on
   ctrls.Priority_Score=TPS.score
```